# Click on EditText crashes device

Tags: android, miui

I'm writing an app that has a few EditText fields. The app has been tested on many different devices with different Android versions and everything went as expected, except on a Xiaomi Mi9 with Android 9 and MIUI Global 10.2.30 stable. On this device, when I click the first EditText, the app stops working, the smartphone locks and appears a message stating that the device has unexpectedly closed.

The odd thing is that I have several EditText fields that are working fine, only the ones for login are causing the problem.

Debugging in Android Studio doesn't show any errors, it's like the app is working fine.

Does anyone know what can be causing this? Has anyone experienced similar issues with this device/MUIU?

Below is my Java and XML code (the same code works well with other EditTexts):

```
public void onLogin(View v) {

   EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
   EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

   sendLogin(etUsername.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString(), new VolleyCallback(){
```

> Layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/design"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:hint="@string/hint_login"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Comment: post your crash logs.

Comment: This is not sufficient, Post full xml

Comment: Do you can remove android:background="@drawable/design ? Are you still getting errors?

Comment: @JakirHossain There's no crash log, while debugging it doesn't crash, only the phone crashes, but I can provide the full log later. I'm not with the computer now.

Comment: @JakirHossain Yup, same thing. I found out later that I only get errors if the EditText is declared in the Java class. But as I said, I'm doing the exact same thing in other parts of the app and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the logcat? It is hard to know without it

Comment: Please put this in a comment. This is not an answer

Comment: Not now but I'll do it later.

Answer (score -1):

I support Emre Aslan comment , maybe the dimension of the drawable file doesn't fit the device screen

Comment: The drawable is used for other EditTexts in the app and works fine.